# Jquery - disable window scrolling with arrow keys on focus of list

Tags: jquery, list, scroll, key

I am trying to make a list navigable using the up/down arrow keys - which worked but pressing these keys causes the window to scroll which is very annoying. So I want to disable to movement of the page using the arrow keys when this box is focused.

I tried:

```
$('.selectionList').focus(function(event){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    return false;
    });
});

$('.selectionList').blur(function(event){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    return true;
    });
});
```

But the re-enabling of these keys did not work to the page wouldn't scroll without the scrollbar. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056562/simple-javascript-question-how-do-i-prevent-scrolling-with-arrow-keys-but-not-t) which I could use but this would disable the use of these keys permanently, which I do not want to happen.

The $('.selectionList').keyup() event is as follows:

```
$('.selectionList').keyup(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13)      //enter
    {
        $('.listNameBox a').click();
    }
    else
    {
    if ((event.keyCode == 38) && ($(this).children('li:eq(' + ($('.selectionList li.selected').index() - 1) + ')').length > 0)) //up
        {
            selectListItem($(this).children('li:eq(' + ($('.selectionList li.selected').index() - 1) + ')'));
        }
    else if ((event.keyCode == 40) && ($(this).children('li:eq(' + ($('.selectionList li.selected').index() + 1) + ')').length > 0)) //down
        {
            selectListItem($(this).children('li:eq(' + ($('.selectionList li.selected').index() + 1) + ')'));
        };
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `.blur()` handler isn't replacing the previous keydown handler, it's adding another one. Try instead using [`$(document).off('keydown')`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) or `$(document).unbind('keydown')` in your `.blur()` handler to _remove_ the previous keydown handler.

Comment: thank you
    $('.selectionList').focus(function(event){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    return false;
    });
    });


    $('.selectionList').blur(function(event){
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
    });

Seems to work

Comment: Cool. I've added my comment as an answer. (I didn't do so originally because I didn't have time at that moment to analyse your keyup function to see if it was part of the problem, but since you say using `.unbind()` fixed things...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.blur()` handler isn't replacing the previous keydown handler, it's adding another one. (And subsequent focus and blur events keep adding more and more.)

Try instead using `$(document).off('keydown')` or `$(document).unbind('keydown')` in your `.blur()` handler to remove the previous keydown handler.

The [`.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is new in jQuery 1.7 and pairs with `.on()`, but for older versions you can use the [`.unbind()` method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). If you have a look at the doco I've linked to you'll see that jQuery gives you control over exactly which handlers are being unbound, but in your case the simple syntax with the event name should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) inserted of binding events like that. It would solve your problem.

```
function prevent(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
}


$('.selectionList').on('focus', function(){
  $(this).on('keydown', prevent);
 });
$('.selectionList').on('blur', function(e){
 $(this).off('keydown', prevent);
};
```