# restore event to default action in jquery after event.prenventdefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056631/2454690) to disable `arrow` and `pgdown` and `pgup` keys actions (scrolling). but I need to set actions of this keys to default (scrolling) after `event.preventDefault()` called in my `jquery` code.

How can I do this.

Comment: Where is the **CODE**???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer without better specifics, but if I understand what you have properly if you have something you can track state with you can preventDefault when you wish to block this behavior and let it fall through otherwise:

Psudocode:

```
var state = {
   blockArrows: true;
}

$('#my_widget').keydown(function(e) {
  if(state.blockArrows) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // ...else allow the event to do its normal thing....///
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse preventDefault(), you need to unbind the original action and then re-call it.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Do stuff until you need to recall the default action
    $(this).unbind('keydown').keydown()
})
```

[How to unbind a listener that is calling event.preventDefault() (using jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-unbind-a-listener-that-is-calling-event-preventdefault-using-jquery#1556696)